# how to make alias to make grep command shorter

Tags: shell, grep, alias

In my coding, I always do  `grep -rnIi "abcabc" . --color`

But, how to make an alias that can let me type only one word with my search string? Is that possible?

Comment: Genuinely curious: what coding are you doing with an alias? I was under the impression they were mostly deprecated and, despite a few days of fervent hacking at oblique possibilities, I could never make them very useful because in almost all script worthy scenarios the shell refused to parse them. Eventually I settled on some compromise involving functions and heredocs that provided something like python's burner lambdas but I sure would prefer aliases...

Comment: @mikeserv I think the OP meant _while_ coding as opposed to in the actual code.

Comment: Bummer. They sure are fast.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Pay attention to the tags on this question. This answer is the correct one given the version of `grep` that's included with CentOS 6 is below version 2.11**

I don't believe you can do this using just an alias (at least not in the form that you've written it - see [@Graeme's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118016/7453) for an alternative syntax).

***NOTE:*** I'll also mention here that @Graeme's solution though correct does not work on CentOS 5 & 6. I've confirmed this and it does in fact appear to be an issue with the version of `grep` (2.11 or older) that's bundled with those distros. The issue appears to be with `grep` not, by default, searching STDIN when no path argument is provided with the `-r` switch. Running `grep -rnIi --color "string"` just hangs indefinitely, attempting to search  STDIN.

Aliases cannot take arguments being passed into them. They're more synonymous to a macro where they can get expanded by the shell to something else.

```
$ alias ll='ls -l'
```

This can then be used like so:

```
$ ll
-or-
$ ll somedir
```

But `somedir` isn't passed to `ll`, rather `ll` is expanded in place to `ls -l` and then replaces `ll` in your command.

#### Back to your question

You can use a function in the shell instead. Functions can take arguments.

```
$ function mygrep { grep -rnIi "$1" . --color; }
```

You then use it like this:

```
$ mygrep "blah"
```

[image: ss of ex]

Comment: "The issue appears to be with grep not, be default, searching the current directory when provided the -r switch." Having a little trouble parsing that.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - is that better?

Comment: slm: please see my comment on Graeme's answer. You can **not** assume grep will use the current dir as a default. grep (should) need both a string and "a place where to look for it". Its default is not "current dir", but "Standard Input", so your tries  (`Running grep -rnIi --color "string" just hangs indefinitely, waiting for a file/path argument to search`) was in fact not waiting for a file/path, but was already grepping the *standard input*. Graeme's `mygrep 'abcabc' .` should work fine on CentOS as on any other "normal" unixes (using bash/sh/many others).

Comment: @slm, you are right, it is the version. Previous behaviour was to ignore the `-r`, so it would just match from `stdin` as usual.

Comment: @OlivierDulac - OK, so I didn't quite explain it correctly but the issue still remains with `grep` on CentOS due to the dated version of grep that's included. Yes, I'm aware that the `grep '...' .` will work, it's just that you cannot do that as an alias, so the function method is the correct solution given the tags set on this particular Q.

Comment: @slm: with `alias mygrep='grep -rnIi --color'` : when you then `mygrep "something" somewhere` it will expand to `grep -rnIi --color "something" somewhere` (and therefore will work as expected). you can have as many arguments after "mygrep" as you want: the first one will be the regexp to look for, the next one(s) will be places to look at/in. (as the alias only expands to "grep -options", the rest of the line will be appended to it by the shell)

Comment: @OlivierDulac - yes I understand that but read the original Q: "alias that can let me type only one word with my search string". He only wanted to have to type 1 word, so the OP obviously didn't understand that you cannot pass arguments in the same sense that one would pass arguments to a function. I understand you can be smart and intelligently construct aliases in savvy ways but given his requirement, and the issue with `grep` + `-r` it wasn't feasible to do it, hence my A.

Comment: @slm: ah, indeed, with that (impossible) requirement I agree. (I focused on the question's title, "make grep command shorter" ^^)

Comment: @OlivierDulac - yes I figured as much, there was much confusion about this in the chatroom too.

Answer (score 11):

This can actually be an alias. The `--color` doesn't have to be at the end, and `grep` always searches the current directory with `-r` if no directory option is given (at least GNU `grep` does). Therefore you can do:

```
alias mygrep='grep -rnIi --color'
```

#### Update

The behaviour of searching the current directory by default was introduced in `GNU grep 2.11`. From the [changelog](http://savannah.gnu.org/news/atom.php?group=grep):

> If no file operand is given, and a command-line -r or equivalent
>     option is given, grep now searches the working directory.  Formerly
>     grep ignored the -r and searched standard input nonrecursively.
>     An -r found in GREP_OPTIONS does not have this new effect.

So, on versions `>=2.11` of `GNU grep`, usage of the alias would be as follows:

```
mygrep PATTERN [PATH...]
```

For versions of `grep` before this, you would have to specify the path every time [@slm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118015/48083) using a function is the best way. Although you could achieve the same usage as above by writing the function like this:

```
mygrep () { grep -rnIi --color "$1" "${2:-.}"; }
```

Assuming, of course, that there is no requirement for the `--color` to be at the end as in the Q...

Comment: actually it works on ubuntu but not Redhat enterprise

Comment: That must be due to an older version of `grep`, I just tried it on Fedora 19 and it worked fine. I've confirmed that it def. doesn't work on CentOS 5 or 6. CentOS 6 =  2.6.3, Fedora 19 = 2.14.

Comment: I've incorporated this issue into my A just so others aren't confused as to why my A is accepted and higher voted, since you're approach would be the more normal course 8-).

Comment: I believe your solution is the easiest and so "more correct" one. But you need to show how it's used:  `mygrep something somewhere` (ex:  `mygrep "abcabc" .` , for the OP's example). Grep needs both something to search for, and where to search it (a file, or a directory, both are valid here). The alias only provides the options, as those can (and *should*) be placed before the arguments.

Comment: Otherwise, with no "place" to search in, it greps the standard input.

Comment: @Oliver, it definitely looks in the current directory for me. I use this behaviour regularly! `grep (GNU grep) 2.16`

Comment: @NoName, updated, the alias works for version `2.11` and upward

Comment: @OlivierDulac - It's not possible to make an alias with arguments sandwiched in between. Without being able to exploit the feature of `grep` in searching the current directory with the `-r` switch, this solution won't work on CentOS 6 + it's def. version of `grep`.